# Constraints on Solve results

Tags: equation-solving, constraint

I'd like to filter the results of a solve giving inequality conditions: let's say I have

```
Solve[f[x]==g[y],y]
```

since i want y as function of x, but I want only the results where `x>k` and  `y<k`... Is there any way to specify this kind of constraints for the solve? How can I otherwise filter the results ?

Answer (score 5):

Please look at the documentation page for Solve where states clearly that inequalities can be directly given as part of the equations. Here is a simple example:

```
In[23]:= Solve[x^2 + 2 x == y && y < 5 && x < 5, y]

Out[23]= {{y -> 
   ConditionalExpression[2 x + x^2, -1 - Sqrt[6] < x < -1 + Sqrt[6]]}}
```

You can filter (select) the results from Solve using Select function with appropriate conditions because the results from Solve are just a list of Rules. For instance:

```
In[24]:= sols = Flatten[y /. Solve[x^2 + 2 x == y^2 + 3, y]]

Out[24]= {-Sqrt[-3 + 2 x + x^2], Sqrt[-3 + 2 x + x^2]}

In[25]:= Select[sols /. x -> 3 , # > 2 &]

Out[25]= {2 Sqrt[3]}
```